# SQL Query conversion from 6.5 to >= SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently i am working on the migration project. Found the below query in a procedure. I am able to get the size of database from sys.master_files table. In WHERE condition segmap is used. I am not able to find the simillar column in sys.master_files. Please help me on this

```
SELECT sum(size) * 2
FROM master..sysusages U
WHERE U.segmap = 3
  AND U.dbid = db_id(@db_name)
```

Comment: I hope you are upgrading to a more recent version than 2008. Otherwise you are going from one non-supported version to another. >.<

Answer (score 1):

SYBASE and SQLSERVER used to share same code base.So as from SYBASE docs..[below is definition of segmap](https://benohead.com/sybase-size-of-data-and-log-segments-for-all-databases/)

> The values of master..sysusages.segmap mean the following:
>
> 3: Data stored on this segment
> 4: Log stored on this segment
> 7: Since 7=4+3, both log and data stored on this segment

So the equivalent would be type='0' which means get only data space